# .load() html after three append()

Tags: jquery, append, load

I want to `load()` some external html that I have to embed in three(!) wrappers. This is the result I need:

```
<body>
    <section class="page">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="backdrop">
                <!-- Loaded HTML -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

The following code works fine and looks clean, however, I want to add many `<section>`, so it would be much nicer to somehow chain those `append()` and the `load()`:

```
$('body')        .append('<section class="page"></section>');
$('section.page').append('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
$('div.wrapper') .append('<div class="backdrop"></div>');
$('div.backdrop').load  ('partials/test.html');
```

I have found a few examples of chaining `append()`, however, I failed to combine them with `load()`.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use three separate `append` calls, and as you point out, the way those are coded won't work if you add multiple sections.

Instead, create the full section fragment, append it to body, and then load into the backdrop:

```
$(
'<section class="page">' +
    '<div class="wrapper">' +
        '<div class="backdrop"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</section>'
)
.appendTo('body')
.find('div.backdrop')
.load('partials/test.html');;
```

That's a bit cleaner if you separate the HTML from the code, e.g.:

```
var sectionTemplate = 
    '<section class="page">' +
        '<div class="wrapper">' +
            '<div class="backdrop"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</section>';
```

then

```
$(sectionTemplate)
.appendTo('body')
.find('div.backdrop')
.load('partials/test.html');;
```

Comment: That's much better! Thanks :)